# Error al cambiar de activity (Kotlin, Android studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

```
    val intent1 = Intent(this, MainActivity2::class.java)
    startActivity(intent1)
```

La palabra java me sale como si fuera un error, y no consigo solucionarlo.
De todos modos al iniciar la app me funciona todo bien y se cambia de actividad.
Pero me gustaria que no me saliera en rojo ese error.

Alguna solución? Gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Es importante revises que dentro de tu `build.gradle` tengas especificado Kotlin (id 'kotlin-android'):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}
```

pero el problema principal se debe a que necesitas el contexto, envialo a tu función y usalo para instanciar el Intent.

```
fun Actividad1(context : Context){
    val intent1 = Intent(context, MainActivity2::class.java)
    startActivity(intent1)
}
```